# Why can I create new files and directories in Azure Cloud Shell Bash, but not PowerShell?

Tags: azure

When I open up Bash in Azure Cloud Shell, I am able to create and edit new files and directories.

But when I try to do it in the PowerShell verison of Azure Cloud Shell, I am not able to do any of those things.

For example, when I try to create a new file:

```
Azure:/
PS Azure:\> new-item -Type file -Path my_new_files.txt
new-item : The node at path 'AzurePSDrive#Azure/my_new_files.txt' does not support the cmdlet 'New-Item'
At line:1 char:1
+ new-item -Type file -Path my_new_files.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (AzurePSDrive#Azure/my_new_files.txt:String) [New-Item], NodeDoesNotSupportCmdletException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItem.NotSupported,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

And when I try to cd into a directory which I already created from the Bash shell:

```
Azure:/
PS Azure:\> ls
clouddrive  jjj  jjj.txt
Azure:/
PS Azure:\> cd jjj
cd : Cannot find path 'Azure:/jjj' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd jjj
+ ~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Azure:/jjj:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Why can I mkdir, touch, cd, and vi in Bash, but none of the file/directory commands seem to work in PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue.  **Azure:** has a virtual mapping to your home directory.  The home directory is stored in a variable called $HOME.

Most of the PowerShell cmdlets don't play nicely with the Azure:\ alias.  To overcome this just type:

`cd $HOME`

Once your in the home directory your cmdlets will work as you have written.